# Which is better: importing .py files or executing .txt files?

Tags: python

Which is better:
Importing .py files or executing .txt files?

For example, there is a .py file with this written, named "python.py":

```py
def MyFunction():
    print(".py file")
```

and there is a .txt file named "text.txt":

```py
def MyFunction()
    print(".txt file")
```

I can use the first one like:

```py
import python
```

and the second one like:

```py
exec(open("text.txt", "r").read())
```

Which method is better in terms of speed, reliability, and safety?
I am not really concerned about the length of each code

Comment: I'd put my personal preference to 99% for import, 1% on `exec()` on **.py** files and 0% on `exec()` for **.txt** files.

Comment: why did the creators of python created `import` if you could do better by reading a text file?

Comment: import is faster for me, it would not exist otherwise

Comment: I suspect that you may be actually looking for a way to dynamically import modules/files. In which case, you should look into [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html), or alternatively `__import__`.

Comment: You can test it (How to measure the execution time of a python script): https://pythonhow.com/measure-execution-time-python-code/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big problem with exec can appear if you exec a module that imports another module.
If this imported module uses relative paths I could imagine this to not work.

Apart from that the only reason I could imagine why you want to use the latter method is dynamic imports if you have a module system for example.
If that is the case, I would recommend you to have a look at [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/importlib.html)

So in terms of speed, reliably and safety always use `import` for normal imports and `importlib` for dynamic imports

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the first one with `.py` file. You should always save python scripts in files with `.py` extension. 4 reasons: Portability, Readability, Useability, Convention.

Answer (score 0):

If your storing python code. 
Then `python_code.py` file is preferable.

If you are storing information like text, or some other raw data. 
Then any type of file can be used. That can be in `.txt`, `.xls`, `.csv`, may be databases.

**Note:**

you have named your file name as **python**. Which is **highly not recommended**.